# What are users of Raspberry Pi called?

Tags: discussion

When I was working on an answer I had to refer to the Raspberry Pi community. Just by whim and completely naturally I referred to the users of Raspberrie Pi's as "Raspberrians"

Not sure what that means.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Haha excellent. I like it.

Comment: Call them the Pious.

Comment: I don't know what I'd call myself, but I do like my pi.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at a social group of any sort there is usually some sort of slangish name associated with the entire group... As you suggested "Raspberrians." But you also need to take sub-cultures into consideration.

For example experts in this field could be called "Pi Heads", novices could be "Raspidiots", and not to specifically say the "Hackers," but the people interested in the modification of specific existing code could be called the "Pi-Crackers" of the community.

Now mind you these are all examples I made up on the spot, and I don't mean them to be real suggestions. (because they aren't very creative) However, I've posted this simply to point out and remind of the potential for multiple names for the members of the community based on the specific subcultural of Pi users the particular person fits into.

As an additional point, @Bryan Dunsmore is right. The use of these names would definitely serve to confuse new users, and would probably be more or less a hindrance to the communities development. But I think it would be fun for the people within the group to be responsible for what they're referred to as!

Comment: Pi Bakers and Pi Tasters.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to call them anything special. *The Raspberry Pi community* will do just fine. It's probably better if we refrain from special phrases that have no meaning outside of here. As they will only serve to confuse users, both old and new, who are not up to date with whatever hip-hop term that people make up.

#### TL;DR Call them *The Raspberry Pi community*.